# Too many queries with repository pattern, entity framework, mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am having an issue still, but I am getting closer with some of the help from people here.

I an using EF Profiler and I see that when I load my dashboard controller that it is running many queries which are pulling back "essentially" the same data form the DB. Here is my controller example:

```
Public Class DashboardController
    Inherits BaseController

    Private ticketRepo As MaintenanceTicketsRepository

    Public Sub New()
        Me.ticketRepo = New MaintenanceTicketsRepository(New TicketContext)
    End Sub

    Function Chart_OpenItemsByPM() As ActionResult
        Dim tickets As IList(Of MaintenanceTicket) = ticketRepo.GetAll().Include(Function(p) p.Priority).Include(Function(s) s.Status).OrderBy(Function(o) o.PriorityId).ToArray()

        Dim queue As PieChartViewModel() = Mapper.Map(Of MaintenanceTicket(), PieChartViewModel())(tickets)

        Dim ticketCounts = From t In queue _
                           Where t.StatusName = "Open" And _
                           t.PriorityName <> "Not Ready" _
                           Group t By t.PriorityName Into Count() _
                           Select New With {
                               .PriorityName = PriorityName,
                               .Id = Count,
                               .Explosion = If(.PriorityName = "Critical", "True", "False")
                           }

        Return Json(ticketCounts)
    End Function

    Function Grid_OpenItemsByPriority(<DataSourceRequest()> request As DataSourceRequest) As ActionResult
        Dim tickets As IList(Of MaintenanceTicket) = ticketRepo.GetAll().Include(Function(p) p.Priority).Include(Function(s) s.Status).ToArray()

        Dim queue As GridViewModel() = Mapper.Map(Of MaintenanceTicket(), GridViewModel())(tickets)

        Dim ticketCounts = From t In queue _
                           Where _
                           t.StatusId = 1 And _
                           t.CreateDate.Year = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Year _
                           Group t By _
                           Column1 = CType(t.CreateDate.Month, Integer), _
                           Column2 = CType(t.CreateDate.ToString("MMMM"), String) _
                           Into g = Group _
                           Order By Column1 _
                           Select New With {
                               .Id = Column1,
                               .Month = Column2,
                               .Critical = g.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 1),
                               .High = g.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 2),
                               .Normal = g.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 3),
                               .Low = g.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 4),
                               .NotReady = g.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 5),
                               .Total = g.Count(Function(t) t.Id <> Nothing)
                           }

        Return Json(ticketCounts.ToDataSourceResult(request))
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        ticketRepo.Dispose()
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You will see that there are functions (which are called via ajax into Kendo Controls) but each function fills the repository, and then maps the data into my viewmodel, and then I need to sort through and do the real procedure to get my final output. I do this in each function and the load time on my page is high and it is spiking the server.

Any ideas on how to load the repo with one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using stored procedures to limit the data returned to my repository, speeding up data access.

Comment: can you explain how?

Comment: Sorry this was at a previous job and quite a long time ago so I cannot give specific detail, but I can say that I called to the DB via SP's that I had setup to get the exact data I needed returned instead of working through inline sql. I wished I had the code so I could have posted it for you.